# EJBCA: Authorization Denied Admin GUI

Tags: ejbca, wildfly-18

I am attempting to upgrade EJBCA.

I attempted to run this on ubuntu 20.04, locally, using wildfly 18. Wildfly 18 results in this error: "CAUSE: Client certificate or OAuth bearer token required."

I have tried this two ways, by importing the keystore, truststore and superadmin from another instance and by creating the CA fresh and using the resulting superadmin.p12.

The home page loads, but the administration gives me the following error:

"AUTHORIZATIONDENIED
CAUSE: Client certificate or OAuth bearer token required. "

I can really use some help with this.

Things I have tried:
(1) I have downloaded superadmin.p12 and imported it into my browsers
(2) I have attempted to upload the superdmin cert:

bin/ejbca.sh ca importcacert ${NAME} ${NAME}.cacert.pem -initauthorization -superadmincn SuperAdmin

- This results in The CA certificate is already imported.
  (3) Both my keystore.jks and truststore.jks are moved into /ejbca/p12 and /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/keystore
  (4) I did set "web.reqcertindb=false"
  (6) I did try to enable ssl on wildfly 14 (https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/infrastructure/wildfly/administration/enable-ssl-wildfly/)
  (7) I have tried a fresh Management_CA as well

The log of /ejbca/adminweb:

```
"08:20:01,270 ERROR [org.ejbca.ui.web.admin.configuration.EjbcaJSFHelperImpl] (default task-4) org.cesecore.authentication.AuthenticationFailedException: Client certificate or OAuth bearer token required.
08:20:01,279 WARN [org.ejbca.ui.web.admin.configuration.EjbcaWebBeanImpl] (default task-4) Language was not initialized for this session
08:20:01,279 WARN [org.ejbca.ui.web.admin.configuration.EjbcaWebBeanImpl]
```

I can provide more information if needs be.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have it running today. Here is what I learned:

- It seems that if you set wildfly up as a service (per instructions) it is going to set up wildfly to run with launch.sh. Launch.sh is going to result in a cipher mistmatch. I needed to run the standalone.sh file instead
- Adminweb must be contacted on 8443
- if you need to run this thing on domain setup your going to need to post another question
  Best,